# accessibilityLabel of UIViewController's title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiaccessibility

Is there anyway to set an `accessibilityLabel` for the title of `UIViewController`? The `title` of view controller is a string, and I'm sure for the title there should be a label somewhere, just how do I access it? Could one of the navigation items be the title?

Thanks!

Edit:
Yes the reason for asking is that I need different accessibilityLabel for the title.

Comment: Do you want the accessibility label to be different than the title?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes that's exactly the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use`titleView`

For example you can put the code in the `viewDidLoad` method

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
label.text = self.title;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

then you can change the `label.text` by changing the title of the view controller

Answer (score 1):

Use the `accessibilityLabel` property of `self`.

For example, you can put this in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.accessibilityLabel = @"Label for accessibility";
```